# Undecryptive encrypting with an ability to operate with encrypted data

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I get latitude and longitude from users and store them within a MySQL database. My service seems to be anonymous so I want to encrypt coordinates in an undecryptive way (like md5 does). But the problem is that I need to compute distance in any moment after writing coords to the DB. So, is there any way to make computing operations within that "encrypted dome"? I use PHP. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why won't you try using symetric encryption ?

Comment: @dariusz.g, if I use it, ANB would be able to decrypt data if I give them a key. So I do not want this, coordinates must be undecryptive anyway.

Comment: You can't not have data and at the same time have it, that's simply not how it works. Password hashing is a special case because you only ever need to compare two hashes for identity, you never need to "do" anything else with the data. If you need the data to "do" something, then you need the data itself.

Comment: md5 hashing is the equivalent of making a burger from a cow; you can never change the burger back into a cow again

Comment: Even if you somehow managed to store the data in a way that obfuscated the data itself but would allow you to calculate the distance to other points, you could easily reverse-engineer the obfuscated point data by triangulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 is hashing, not encryption. Therefore you are losing information, that can never be restored again. With lost information you can't do any calculations.

What you need is a true encryption, which then works both ways, to decrypt your data. There is no way around it.